# How to increment / work with AssetId

Tags: assets

I struggle understanding conversion. I found a lot of questions here and online that state that converting between substrate primitives and rust primitives can easily be handled with `into()` calls or the `Saturated` package or other stuff.

I'm trying this with https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L197

There is this (hopelessly outdated) example here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/assets#simple-code-snippet

... that does not work with the current version of pallet assets for ages.

However, so I have:

```rust
type AssetIdOf<T> = <T as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId;

...

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn get_next_asset_id)]
pub type NextAssetId<T> = StorageValue<_, AssetIdOf<T>, ValueQuery>;
```

and basically all I want to do is add `1` to `NextAssetId`.

I tried everything but it says that it missed `From<u32>` (on into) or can't add if I do something like `<NextAssetId<T>>::mutate(|asset_id| *asset_id += 1);` or even `<NextAssetId<T>>::mutate(|asset_id| *asset_id += One::one());` as in a very old commit on the repo.

I'm not sure if i attack this problem correctly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in order to achieve what you're trying to do, you need to put an explicit trait bound in your pallet's config, enforcing `AssetId` type to be incrementable.

I would do it like this (assuming we're tightly coupling):

```rust
use frame_support::sp_runtime::traits::{Saturating, One};

...

#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: pallet_assets::Config {
    type AssetId: IsType<<T as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId>
        + Saturating
        + One;
}

type AssetIdOf<T> = <T as Config>::AssetId;
```

Then you should be able to increment values of type `AssetId` like this:

```rust
asset_id.saturating_inc();
```

Comment: This works, but I have to add Parameter, Default, MaxEncodedLen as traits for the storage.

What I don't understand: Why do I have to add them again? Isn't the `IsType` bit defining it as AssetId from config which in turn already has this trait?

Comment: @shredding I think `IsType` only allows to convert back and forth, but isn't so smart to tell the compiler that type A implements all the traits which type B does. You would probably need a macro for that.